# return value in localStorage as an Int in js?

Tags: javascript, string, parseint

I understand that localStorage only stores strings, but lets say the string is '43', would there be a way of printing this as an int?

I tried parseInt() but I keep getting NaN..

Comment: please show the value retrieved from local storage and how it is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use isNaN() function to determine whether a value is an illegal number (Not-a-Number). If it is a number, you can pass it into parseInt(). Please let me know if you have other issues.